# Linked list not freed, missing memory leak

Tags: c, malloc, free

I'm currently playing with linked lists, and I've put together the following code for testing purposes.

First I'd like to point out, I'm aware of my unusual list setup, it was just a test, to get a not upside down list. My actual "problem" now is, that I don't seem to have any memory leaks once the program terminates, although I'm not freeing the list. I'm using [drmemory](http://drmemory.org/) on Windows for analyzing, and it always worked nicely. If I put some other mallocs in this code, it notices the not freed memory. Why doesn't it notice the list?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

// ----------------------

typedef struct Item
{
    char name[10];
    struct Item *next;
} Item;

Item *items = NULL;

Item *items_add(const char* name)
{
    Item *new = malloc( sizeof(Item) );
    strcpy(new->name, name);
    new->next = NULL;

    if(items == NULL)
    {
        items = new;
    }
    else
    {
        Item *iter = items;
        while(iter->next != NULL)
        {
            iter = iter->next;
        }

        iter->next = new;
    }

    return new;
}

void items_rem(const char* name)
{
    if(items == NULL)
        return;

    Item *iter = items, *prev;
    do
    {
        if(strcmp(iter->name, name) == 0)
        {
            prev->next = iter->next;
            free(iter);
            break;
        }

        prev = iter;
        iter = iter->next;
    }
    while(iter->next);
}

// ----------------------

int main(void)
{
    items_add("Item1");
    items_add("Item2");
    items_add("Item3");
    items_add("Item4");

    items_rem("Item3");

    for(Item *iter = items; iter != NULL; iter = iter->next)
    {
        printf("%s\n", iter->name);
    }

    /*
        Output:
            Item1
            Item2
            Item4
    */
}
```

Comment: +1 for Playing with linked list.

Comment: It seems `prev->next`  is used uninitialized during the removal of first element.

Comment: @EAGER_STUDENT: You're right, thanks. Didn't really think about the case of only one item being in the list, before posting this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason, I can think of is that `Item *items = NULL` 'items' is a global variable. So, as far as the memory leak checking tool is concerned, the memory is still accessible from the code, so it may be assuming that you still need that memory.

Atleast IBM Rational Purify works in this way. In IBM Rational Purify, you can select the option to show "Memory in use" and it will display this pointer and number of bytes held by it.

Please note that a memory is considered leaked only when there are no pointer variables containing that address and it has not been freed also.

For Ex:

```
int main()
{
  function();  
}

int function()
{
   char *ptr = NULL;    
   ptr = malloc(10);     
   return 0;    
}
```

Now, in the above example, once you return from function, there is no way for you to access variable `ptr`. So, the memory allocated for ptr is ***definitely lost***

Comment: Ah~ of course! Shame on me for not thinking about that. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

drmemory doesn't show reachable allocations by default, try running `drmemory` with the `-show_reachable` option set